# How to validate decimal value

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, sharepoint-list, column-validation, list-validation

I am working on SharePoint list validation. In column A, it should only allowed whole number/integer to be entered and any decimal should return an error.

I tried to set the number of decimal place to zero but it turn out the column will round it off when decimals value entered. This is not the desired validation, it should return error.
[image]

It is much appreciated if anyone can help me out with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below formula in column validation:

```
=IF([Number Column] = ROUND([Number Column], 0), true, false)
```

[image]

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Replace `[Number Column]` in formula by display name of your column.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your column validation(change the number to your column name).

```
=number=ROUND(number,0)
```

Test result:

[image]